# How can I fix emacs indentation of C++ initializers?

Tags: emacs, elisp, auto-indent

Emacs doesn't properly indent C++ class definitions for allocators that have initializers with colons in them. I think that this is because lines with colons are left-indented in many cases.

I would like to fix this.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

EMACS indents the code like this:

```
class demo {
    int x;
    demo(){
    }
 demo(int y):x(y){
    };
};
```

But it should really indent it like this:

```
class demo {
    int x;
    demo(){
    }
    demo(int y):x(y){
    };
};
```

Is there a way to fix this behavior? Presumably we need some elisp...

Thanks!

Comment: @nightcracker: I think Emacs questions here are fine. Moreover, this could easily have a solution involving programming in elisp, and it is unquestionably programming-related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs (at least version 23) doesn't do this in C mode, but it does in C++ mode since in C the part before the colon can only be a label. Make sure you're in C++ mode (`M-x c++-mode`).

Comment: You are right!  .h defaults to C mode; I changed it to C++ mode in my .emacs file. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to use `.hpp` for C++ header files.

Comment: Oh, I find .hpp so tremendously gross.